# NotificationChannel notification as alarm when phone is muted (Oreo)

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-alarms, notification-channel

I'm setting the **NotificationCompat.Builder** with:

```
.setSound(getNotificationSound(), AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)
.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
```

among the other mandatory properties.

For the **NotificationChannel** that I'm using, I added:

```
.setBypassDnd(true)
```

For Oreo, the problem is that:

- the fired notification doesn't have any sound when the phone is muted or on vibrate so it's not acting like an alarm

What's the point of *Do not disturb custom exception* toggle button from a notification category/channel? Can it help to achieve my goal because I didn't see any differences?

For versions older than Oreo, where I'm not using the NotificationChannel I have a behavior which I prefer:

- notification sound works when the phone is muted but no vibration
- notification sound AND vibration works when the phone is on vibration or with sound enabled

Any ideas how to solve this inconsistency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave up using the notification channels for sound and vibration to get consistent results across Android versions.

```
channel.setSound(null, null);
```

and used the `MediaPlayer` and `Vibrator` instead with a helper class like this:

```
public class RingtoneAndVibrationPlayer extends ContextWrapper{

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private Vibrator mVibrator;

public RingtoneAndVibrationPlayer(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void play() {
    try {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mVibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(PreferenceHelper.getNotificationSound();

        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri);
        if (PreferenceHelper.isRingtoneEnabled()) {
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(PreferenceHelper.isRingtoneInsistent());
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }

        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        if (PreferenceHelper.isVibrationEnabled()) {
            mVibrator.vibrate(new long[] {0, 500, 500, 500},
                    PreferenceHelper.isRingtoneInsistent() ? 2 : -1);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {
        stop();
    }
}

public void stop() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mVibrator != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
    if (mVibrator != null) {
        mVibrator.cancel();
    }
}
}
```

The only dissadvantage that I see is that a user could manually change the sound and vibration settings of a notification channel which will play along with the ones above.
In my case, this is discouraged by having explicit preferences for sound and vibration in the app's settings.

Comment: May I know, in term of Notification context, when do you initiate `RingtoneAndVibrationPlayer` creation, and how do you store the reference to your `RingtoneAndVibrationPlayer`? Because, some where at the point, we need a reference to `RingtoneAndVibrationPlayer`, so that we can call `stop()`? Thank you.

Comment: In my use case, I have a RingtoneAndVibrationPlayer member in my Service, initialized in onCreate and then used.